# Trying to understand the signature of a C# method

Tags: c#, opencv, emgucv

Following is from the EMGU CV documentation (taken from [here](http://www.emgu.com/wiki/files/2.4.10/document/html/e0764906-a5b4-340e-0ed2-0dd969ff80ca.htm)):

```
DenseHistogram.Calculate<TDepth> Method (Image<Gray, TDepth>[], 
    Boolean, Image<Gray, Byte>)
```

And the following is sample usage from an actual application:

```
dh.Calculate(new Image<Gray, Byte>[] { img[0] }, false, null);
```

where `dh` has been created as a `DenseHistogram`.

What purpose does the `<TDepth>` serve (immediately after `Calculate`)? It has not been used in the sample code, but does not seem to cause a problem, although nothing in the documentation indicates it is optional.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a [generic type parameter](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0zk36dx2.aspx), which is what makes the method generic.

In the sample code the type parameter is inferred, i.e. the compiler figures out from the parameters used what the type parameter has to be. The complete call without the type parameter being inferred would be:

```
dh.Calculate<Byte>(new Image<Gray, Byte>[] { img[0] }, false, null);
```

Comment: Thanks.  Can we say then, had none of the parameters contained a `TDepth`, the compiler could not have inferred it?

Comment: @ScottChamberlain: Yes, if you for example would try to call `dh.Calculate(null, false, null);` you would get a compiler error telling you that the type could not be inferred. You would either have to specify the type parameter, or cast the first null reference: `dh.Calculate((Image<Gray, Byte>)null, false, null);`

Comment: FYI: Tried `dh.Calculate(null, false, null);` - did not get a compiler error, but did get a runtime null reference exception.

Comment: @Sabuncu: Check if there is a non-generic overload of the method.

Comment: Yes there is! -- this: `DenseHistogram.Calculate Method (IImage[], Boolean, Image(Gray, Byte))` -- the first argument is completely different, but `null` fits everything, am I right?

Comment: @Sabuncu: Yes, a null reference fits any reference or nullable type.

Answer (score 2):

It's the generic `Type`-parameter for the `Calculate` method which is a [generic method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/twcad0zb.aspx). That's a method that can accept any `Type` (in this case - for the second Type of `Image`). Generic methods that can infer the `Type` - do not need it explicitly specified.

Here's a very simple example:

```
string ArrayLength<T>(T[] a)
{
    return a.Length.ToString();
}
```

And use:

```
int[] i = { 1, 2, 3 };
Text = ArrayLength(i);
```

The following, on the other hand:

```
Text = ArrayLength(null);
```

shows: `The type arguments for method 'Test.Form1.Example<T>(T[])' cannot be inferred from the usage.` The solution for this is to use:

```
Text = ArrayLength<int>(null);
```

(Which then throws a `NullReferenceException` at the `Length` property, of course.)

Comment: Thank you, for the link and the sample.

Comment: ispiro, I gave the answer to Guffa because he was first to provide the example that uses `<Byte>` taken from the sample code.  I have upvoted your answer, and I **sincerely** thank you for your help.

Comment: >`(Which then throws a NullReferenceException at the Length property, of course.)` This is exactly what happened to me (see comments under other answer). Thanks.